# Firebase is referencing an old project and not the current one

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

In my new project, I am making sure that users do not have to go to the login screen every time they open the app by using the following code:

```
// this means that there is a user logged in... take them to the main view.
    if let x = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
        print("The current user is: \(x)")
        // first param is storyboard name
        self.setTheRootViewController("Main", identifier: "GroupChatsView")
    }
    // take them to the login view controller
    else {
        self.setTheRootViewController("Main", identifier: "LoginView")
    }
```

I have not created any users yet, so I would expect this code to take me to the login view every time. But, For some odd reason, when I print out the current user's unique id, it is my own unique id from a previous project. I am not sure what to do at this point. Also, everything in my GoogleService-Info.plist matches up with my new project.

When I logout of my other app in the iOS simulator, the code functions as expected.

Are there any easy workarounds for this? Thanks.

Comment: have you set your new firebase url?

Comment: No. What would that look like?

Comment: sorry, when I first read didnt see that you have verified your  `GoogleService-Info.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

In your simulator clean and reset settings ! It does the trick.

Comment: So you think this is just a simulator error and won't affect users when the app is published?

Comment: Normally if you reset now simulator it has to work. It doesn't ? Data are shown or there is a bug ?

Comment: no it works when I reset it. I'm just worried about it not working once the app is actually live.

Comment: It happens when you modify the body of the database and I don't think you're going to often change it. For the moment I don't know the right way to reload current database but firebase should have one.